# Free resolutions of universal enveloping algebras for simple, finite dimensional Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, lie-algebras, associative-algebras

I'm currently studying [Anick's resolution](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-homology-of-associative-algebras-Anick/f68724d672f03dd5593ac8669e1110972db76d56) on the context of universal enveloping algebras for certain Lie algebras, namely some of the smallest cases: $A_1,A_2,A_3,B_2,G_2$, and so on.

What are some references on other free resolutions that are convenient for universal enveloping algebras for simple, finite dimensional Lie algebras? Free resolutions of associative algebras in general (such as Anick's resolution) are also welcome. I'm aware that [the bar resolution "induces" Anick's resolution](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-9730-4_6).